# Router-outlet is not updating after Routerlink navigation

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular6, router-outlet

I'm creating a simple Angular app with a navigation menu. Each menu item has a `Routerlink` to navigate between the pages. Here's the pages :

- Home (`#/home`)
- Customer / Info (`#/customer/info`)
- Customer / Details (`#/customer/details`)
- Customer / Details / b0 (`#/customer/details/b0`)
- Customer / Details / b1 (`#/customer/details/b1`)

Relevant code :

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      [
        {
          path: "",
          redirectTo: "home",
          pathMatch: "full"
        },
        {
          path: "home",
          component: HomeComponent
        },
        {
          path: "customer",
          component: CustomerComponent,
          children: [
            {
              path: "",
              redirectTo: "info",
              pathMatch: "full"
            },
            {
              path: "info",
              component: CustomerInfoComponent,
            },
            {
              path: "details",
              component: CustomerDetailsComponent,
              children: [
                {
                  path: "",
                  redirectTo: "b0",
                  pathMatch: "full"
                },
                {
                  path: "b0",
                  component: CustomerDetailsBlock0Component
                },
                {
                  path: "b1",
                  component: CustomerDetailsBlock1Component
                },
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      {useHash: true}
    )
    ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, CustomerComponent, MenuComponent, HomeComponent, CustomerInfoComponent, CustomerDetailsComponent, CustomerDetailsBlock0Component, CustomerDetailsBlock1Component ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**customer-component.html**

```
<p>This is customer #{{id}}</p>
<app-menu>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-menu>
```

**customer-details-component.html**

```
<p>This is customer details</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**customer-details-block0-component.html**

```
<p>details block0</p>
```

**customer-details-block1-component.html**

```
<p>details block1</p>
```

**menu-component.html**

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a routerLink="">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a routerLink="../customer">Customer</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a routerLink="../customer/info">Info</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a routerLink="../customer/details">Details</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a routerLink="../customer/details/b0">Block #0</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a routerLink="../customer/details/b1">Block #1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>------------- Content inside menu router-outlet -------------</p>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <p>--------------------------------------------------------------------</p>
</div>
```

---

The navigation works fine : when I click on a link, the activated route changed, the `router-outlet` are updated and the expected components are displayed.

The problem comes when I refresh the page when the route is `#/customer/details/b1` (or if I click directly on it, without clicking on the parent menu item) : The components are the good ones, but my menu is broken. If I click on the link to go the `#/customer/details/b0` the route is changed but the router-outlet are not updated, the `b1` component is still displayed and `b0` isn't.
This is fixed when I click on another menu item where the URL does not starts with "customer/details", for example if I click on "Info" then the issue is gone.

[image: Angular_router_bug]
[image: Angular_router_bug_2]

I guess it's a problem about the component `customer-details` being the same instance and so Angular reuse it. But then why the child components are not changed ?

I managed to "fix" this behavior by returning false everytime the router [shouldReuseRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy#shouldReuseRoute) function is called :

```
// menu-component.ts
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
}
```

But I do not want the destroy/create all my components every time. Are there any solutions to this ?

Here's the [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-outlet-bug). To reproduce the bug :

1. Click on the link "Block #1"
2. Refresh the Stackblitz output window
3. Click on "Block #0" or "Details" : the route is changed but the message is still "details block1"
4. Click on "Info"
5. Repeat step 1. -> now the problem is fixed.

---

**EDIT:** I still have the issue with Angular v6.1.3 (I updated the [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-outlet-bug)). I tried all the solutions provided by @mast3rd3mon but nothing seems to fix it.

Comment: i could be wrong but i thought the router link had to be in binding brackets? `[routerLink]="../customer"`? it could also be because you use `../customer` instead of `/customer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from the `MenuComponent`. You have to insert `<ng-content></ng-content>` instead of `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` because the component behind `<router-outler></router-outlet>` is init in the component which call the `MenuComponent` (`CustomerComponent` in this example).

So the code in `menu.component.html` should be :

```
<p>------------- Content inside menu router-outlet -------------</p>
<ng-content></ng-content>
<p>--------------------------------------------------------------------</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

After looking at the demo you made, you need to remove the `..` part of the router links. `../customer` becomes `/customer`, `../customer/info` becomes `/customer/info` etc.

It might have just been the demo but make sure that the app.component.html file looks like `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` not `<router-outlet>` as the tag needs to have a closing tag.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I updated the demo with the fixed router-outlet tag in app.component.html and the ".." in the router links. But the issue is still the same.

Comment: did you stop and rerun `ng serve` or whatever you used?

Comment: after trying other things, i removed the `useHash` because i think that might have been causing interference. i also `RouterModule,` above `RouterModule.forRoot(....)` and i cant seem to reproduce your issue now

Comment: I removed the useHash option but I still get the same problem. I also tried to change the router links using [routerLinks]="['/customer/details/b0']" or [routerLinks]="['/customer', 'details', 'b0']" but nothing seems to fix it.

Comment: did you add the `RouterModule,` above the `RouterModule.forRoot(....)`?

Comment: Yes I added it above and below, but this has no effect.

Comment: strange, after those changes, i was unable to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

Merge `CustomerDetailsBlock0Component`, `CustomerDetailsBlock1Component` into `CustomerDetailsBlockComponent` with route param ':blockId'

```
CustomerDetailsBlockComponent{
   
  blockId: number

  constructor(private router Router){
        this.router.events.subscribe(event=>{
            if (event instanceof ActivationEnd && event.snapshot) {
                let blockId = +event.snapshot.paramMap.get('blockId')
                if (blockId) {
                    this.blockId = blockId
                    //update other angular bindings
                }
            }
        })
  }

}
```